# Put only one powershell object in the variable "register" from ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

I have an Object in my powershell script and I would like to have it and only it in my variable register, but i don't know what I need to do.

Code of my playbook.yaml :

```
- name: firsttest
  hosts: win
  tasks:
   - name: Ping my Windows vm
     win_ping:

   - name: Run basic PowerShell script
     ansible.windows.win_powershell:
       script: |
         $hostname = hostname
         $domain = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Domain | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Enabled | Out-String
         $private = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Private | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Enabled | Out-String
         $public = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Public | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Enabled | Out-String
         $ipaddress = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress | Out-String
        
         $myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
          "Hostname" = $hostname
          "IPAdress" = $ipaddress
          "Domain" = $domain
          "Private" = $private
          "Public" = $public
         }
     register: result

   - name: Show PS_output
     debug:
       var: result
```

The result in my ansible console :

```
"result": {
        "changed": true,
        "debug": [],
        "error": [],
        "failed": false,
        "host_err": "",
        "host_out": "",
        "information": [],
        "output": [],
        "result": {},
        "verbose": [],
        "warning": []
    }
```

On the result above I want to have something like that :

"Hostname" = "Node-Ansible1"

"IPAdress" = 192.168.0.1

"Domain" = "true"

"Private" = "false"

"Public" = "false"

Comment: You probably want to remove `$myObject = `

Comment: You need to use $Ansible.Result to return anything - (see docs https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html#return-result - specifically "The values that were set by $Ansible.Result in the script. Defaults to an empty dict but can be set to anything by the script.")

Comment: Thank you it works, I got the object but it's normal that my result stay in the ansible console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to use $Ansible.Result and add my object in.
The output in the ansible console show my object.

```
- name: firsttest
  hosts: win
  tasks:
   - name: Ping my Windows vm
     win_ping:

   - name: Run basic PowerShell script
     ansible.windows.win_powershell:
       script: |
         $hostname = hostname
         $domain = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Domain | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Enabled | Out-String
         $private = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Private | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Enabled | Out-String
         $public = Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Public | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Enabled | Out-String
         $ipaddress = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress | Out-String
        
         $myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
          "Hostname" = $hostname
          "IPAdress" = $ipaddress
          "Domain" = $domain
          "Private" = $private
          "Public" = $public
         }
     $Ansible.Result = $myObject
     register: result

   - name: Show PS_output
     debug:
       var: result
```